# Pulp.pulpTestAll() test failed, too many values to unpack

Tags: python, gurobi, pulp

My OS is window 7, Pulp version is 1.6.1, gurobi version is 7.0.1. gurobipy can be successfully imported. pulp.solvers.GUROBI did pass the test, so I could use gurobi. However pulp.solvers.CPLEX_CMD failed. Here is the error message:

```
pulp.pulpTestAll()
     Testing zero subtraction
     Testing inconsistant lp solution
     Testing continuous LP solution
     Testing maximize continuous LP solution
     Testing unbounded continuous LP solution
     Testing Long Names
     Testing repeated Names
     Testing zero constraint
     Testing zero objective
     Testing LpVariable (not LpAffineExpression) objective
     Testing Long lines in LP
     Testing LpAffineExpression divide
     Testing MIP solution
     Testing MIP solution with floats in objective
     Testing MIP relaxation
     Testing feasibility problem (no objective)
     Testing an infeasible problem
     Testing an integer infeasible problem
     Testing column based modelling
     Testing dual variables and slacks reporting
     Testing fractional constraints
     Testing elastic constraints (no change)
     Testing elastic constraints (freebound)
     Testing elastic constraints (penalty unchanged)
     Testing elastic constraints (penalty unbounded)
* Solver pulp.solvers.PULP_CBC_CMD passed.
Solver pulp.solvers.CPLEX_DLL unavailable
     Testing zero subtraction
     Testing inconsistant lp solution
     Testing continuous LP solution
     Testing maximize continuous LP solution
     Testing unbounded continuous LP solution
     Testing Long Names
     Testing repeated Names
     Testing zero constraint
'_dummy'
('* Solver', <class pulp.solvers.CPLEX_CMD at 0x000000000B224CA8>,    'failed.')
Solver pulp.solvers.CPLEX_PY unavailable
Solver pulp.solvers.COIN_CMD unavailable
Solver pulp.solvers.COINMP_DLL unavailable
Solver pulp.solvers.GLPK_CMD unavailable
Solver pulp.solvers.XPRESS unavailable
     Testing zero subtraction
     Testing inconsistant lp solution
     Testing continuous LP solution
     Testing maximize continuous LP solution
     Testing unbounded continuous LP solution
     Testing Long Names
     Testing repeated Names
     Testing zero constraint
     Testing zero objective
     Testing LpVariable (not LpAffineExpression) objective
     Testing LpAffineExpression divide
     Testing MIP solution
     Testing MIP solution with floats in objective
     Testing MIP relaxation
     Testing feasibility problem (no objective)
     Testing an infeasible problem
     Testing an integer infeasible problem
     Testing column based modelling
     Testing Sequential Solves
     Testing fractional constraints
     Testing elastic constraints (no change)
     Testing elastic constraints (freebound)
     Testing elastic constraints (penalty unchanged)
     Testing elastic constraints (penalty unbounded)
* Solver pulp.solvers.GUROBI passed.
     Testing zero subtraction
     Testing inconsistant lp solution
     Testing continuous LP solution
too many values to unpack
('* Solver', <class pulp.solvers.GUROBI_CMD at 0x000000000B224FA8>, 'failed.')
Solver pulp.solvers.PYGLPK unavailable
Solver pulp.solvers.YAPOSIB unavailable
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-94f8f423594d>", line 1, in <module>
    pulp.pulpTestAll()

  File "C:\Users\Guodong\Software\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py",     line 2283, in pulpTestAll
    raise PulpError("Tests Failed")

PulpError: Tests Failed
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @SashaZd, no, i just ignored the error

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. It was a problem with Gurobi_CMD. Gurobi passes all the tests, but they fail on Gurobi_CMD.

I solved it by uninstalling and reinstalling Gurobi, and changing the .cfg files for PuLP to correctly point to the Gurobi installation.