# Pulp.pulpTestAll() test failed on "Testing zero constraint"

Tags: python, anaconda, cplex, pulp

I am using anaconda version 1.6.14, python version 3.6.5, pulp version 1.6.8 and CPLEX version 12.8.

When I run pulp.pulpTestAll() coin passes and CPLEX_CMD fails on testing zero constraint (see output below).

The same output is given in this question: [Pulp.pulpTestAll() test failed, too many values to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838567/pulp-pulptestall-test-failed-too-many-values-to-unpack/51177351?noredirect=1#comment89337413_51177351)
But the question is asking why GUROBI failed not why CPLEX failed, and therefore the answers provided there do not answer my question.

The output of pulp.pulpTestAll() is:

```
pulp.pulpTestAll()
         Testing zero subtraction
         Testing inconsistant lp solution
         Testing continuous LP solution
         Testing maximize continuous LP solution
         Testing unbounded continuous LP solution
         Testing Long Names
         Testing repeated Names
         Testing zero constraint
         Testing zero objective
         Testing LpVariable (not LpAffineExpression) objective
         Testing Long lines in LP
         Testing LpAffineExpression divide
         Testing MIP solution
         Testing MIP solution with floats in objective
         Testing MIP relaxation
         Testing feasibility problem (no objective)
         Testing an infeasible problem
         Testing an integer infeasible problem
         Testing column based modelling
         Testing dual variables and slacks reporting
         Testing fractional constraints
         Testing elastic constraints (no change)
         Testing elastic constraints (freebound)
         Testing elastic constraints (penalty unchanged)
         Testing elastic constraints (penalty unbounded)
* Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.PULP_CBC_CMD'> passed.
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_DLL'> unavailable
         Testing zero subtraction
         Testing inconsistant lp solution
         Testing continuous LP solution
         Testing maximize continuous LP solution
         Testing unbounded continuous LP solution
         Testing Long Names
         Testing repeated Names
         Testing zero constraint
'_dummy'
* Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_CMD'> failed.
         Testing zero subtraction
         Testing inconsistant lp solution
         Testing continuous LP solution
         Testing maximize continuous LP solution
         Testing unbounded continuous LP solution
Failure: status == -2 not in [-1]
Failure: status == Unbounded not in ['Infeasible']
Tests failed for solver <pulp.solvers.CPLEX_PY object at 0x7f7aaef0f898>
* Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_PY'> failed.
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.COIN_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.COINMP_DLL'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GLPK_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.XPRESS'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GUROBI'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GUROBI_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.PYGLPK'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.YAPOSIB'> unavailable
```

Comment: Why not ask the authors of PuLP? If you look at the open issues on [github](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/issues), there are several related to your question.

Comment: Thank you @rkersh. I've already commented on a similar question there on github with no response so I was hopeing I might hit a winder audience here :)